# How do I fetch the final link of a redirect without visiting the redirected link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building an affiliate link tracker using JavaScript. I am able to fetch all the URLs,say from a youtube video's description but I am unable to retrieve the final URL, as youtube sends us a redirect link which then parses into the original destination. Is there any way by which I can retrieve the final URL of the destination site from youtube's redirection without visiting the site?

Example: This is the original link I received after running my code in the console.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/redirectevent=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa1BVUEFyMGtFaXE4bEQtM3VEb3gzMW5JNjdnd3xBQ3Jtc0ttSVFLZ05kbkxvNTRBXzR3dDZhd1FId3VVUmwtbDVfUTF3Y2JNYU9pQnRqSDdFd1dJemJobWJtc1g3TV9jUUt0UllxOExqNHp5bVA3dVhGcV8xNjJFN0FqTnlXN3F4MkxOaDVjWlAzR2dFS1BHZnBtUQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Famzn.to%2F3aXvv9J

But the actual link after redirection is this

Link: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0749GV5L3/ref=as_li_qf_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=lovebabbar3-21&creative=24630&linkCode=as2&creativeASIN=B0749GV5L3&linkId=ac766755fe714aff2b2aec9f9564f97f

I want to get the latter link through which I can detect the affiliate id and log it as an affiliate link.

This is my code so far :

```
/*Creating an array to store all the hrefs of the page*/

var arr=[];
var l=document.links;
for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++)
{
arr.push(l[i].href)
}

/* logging all the links fetched for my reference*/
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Edit : I want to build something like this

[Here's a McAffe site link checker which determines if the link is safe or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJfq.png)

Comment: "*without visiting the site*" - no, because that's what redirects. How do you know where should you go, if you don't ask it?

Comment: [There are different ways to redirect.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) If it is done via a `30x`-code, you can make a simple ajax request with [method HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) and get the new URL in the `Location` header.  If it's done via meta-tag, or via JS, I'd suggest a headless browser like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Ohh okay then, what do you recommend me to do next in order to complete the project. It would be really helpful if you can shed some light on it.

Comment: @Thomas can you pls checkout my edits in the question and let me know how I can go about it?Thanks.

Comment: Don't! You don't understand how to build it, let alone how to build it right. And I don't think you understand the possible implications of such a "feature". Do you really want to be legally liable for possible damages if your script returns a false positive and something happens?

Comment: I am building it as my personal project not as a standalone web app to publish on the internet. Anyways thanks for your time. I'll figure out how to go about it.